# sed extract something from string

Tags: unix, sed

I have a string " r1/pkg/amd64/misc/hash/hash-r1.r5218.tbz"
but, I only want "hash-r1.r5218.tbz"

so, I try this

```
 unix$ a="r1/pkg/amd64/misc/hash/hash-r1.r5218.tbz"
 unix$ echo $a | sed 's/.*\/\([^\/]*\)\.tbz/\1/'  //[1]
 hash-r1.r5218   //I know this should work

 unix$ echo $a | sed 's/.*\/\([^\/]+\)\.tbz/\1/'  //[2]
 r1/pkg/amd64/misc/hash/hash-r1.r5218.tbz    //however I do not know why it does not work.
```

as far as I remember, + in regexp, means using previous regexp 1 or more times. * in regexp, means using previous regexp 0 or more times.

Could anyone explain why [2] fails, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all versions of `sed` support `+` in the regex.  Some that do support it require `-r` to be specified.  But why use `sed` instead of `basename` or `echo ${a##*/}`?

Comment: since variable manipulation require us using two statements to do one thing (get rid of */ and then get rid of .tbz (%%.*), I feel sed is more convenient. But, I think variable manipulation is more efficient than pipe ? (I haven't tested it)

Answer (score 2):

```
a="r1/pkg/amd64/misc/hash/hash-r1.r5218.tbz"
echo $a | sed 's:.*/::; s:.tbz$::'
hash-r1.r5218
```

You don't need to use '/' as the patern/repl marker, you can use other chars. The ':' is very popular.

Also, you don't have to use capture buffers, when you know the exact text on both sides of your target data.

I have substituted out all chars up to the last '/', relying on `.*` for all chars, and '/' to terminate the standard greedy search of sed.  THe you sub out the trailing `\.tbz` with noting.

IHTH.

Answer (score 0):

Using this submatch via parentheses will grab everything after the last slash to the end of your line.

```
str="r1/pkg/amd64/misc/hash/hash-r1.r5218.tbz"
echo $str | sed -n -E -e 's/.+\/(.+)$/\1/p'
```

returns hash-r1.r5218.tbz

Oh, and your #2 fails because sed by default prints out each line that has a match.  Using the -n flag suppresses that, and the trailing 'p' on this regex prints out the replace part of the substitution.